# Dynamically create items on Layout, on QSpin Clicked - delete does not remove items

Tags: qt, layout

I want to dynamically create X labels on a layout. The X is taken from the QSpinBox.

When X is decreased, I need to first remove items on layout and then create a new one, with decreased number of labels:

```
void dial::quantity1SpinClicked(int val)
{
    QLayout *layout = fqbox->layout();
    if(layout != 0)
    {
        QLayoutItem *item;
        while ((item = layout->takeAt(0)) != 0)
            layout->removeItem (item);
        delete layout;
    }

    QGridLayout *gridLayout = new QGridLayout;

    QList<QLabel*> labels;

    for (int i = 0; i < val; ++i){
        labels << new QLabel(QObject::tr("nr %1").arg(i));
        gridLayout->addWidget(labels.at(i), i, 0);
    }

    fqbox->setLayout(gridLayout);
}
```

However, my code does not remove items, it creates a new layout, on top on the old one (it looks like so):

[image]

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is needed to delete `QLabel` widget:

```
    QLayoutItem *item;
    while ((item = layout->takeAt(0)) != 0) {
        layout->removeItem (item);
        delete item->widget();
        delete item;
    }
```

Note also description of [`QLayout::removeItem(QLayoutItem * item)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#removeItem):

> It is the caller's responsibility to delete the item.
>
> Notice that item can be a layout (since `QLayout` inherits
>   `QLayoutItem`).